# PhoneGap plugin for Instagram video sharing

Tags: library, video, sharing, mobile, instagram

I'm working on a PhoneGap app for iOS and Android, and we want to share a video to Instagram.

Currently the video is coming from YouTube as a link (being a video that the user has created), otherwise it can be a locally-stored video.

Is there an existing PhoneGap or Cordova plugin that achieves this?

Comment: Try This Link it Might be helpful to you
[Here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)